# Asp.Net Textbox spell checker control

Tags: asp.net, textbox, controls, spell-checking

Does anyone know if any spell checker controls exist for Asp.Net textboxes? I need a control that will check the textbox currently being edited by the user and prompt them of spelling mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik do one which is quite good see:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/spell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a Checkspelling project on codeplex that might help ?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/checkspelling.aspx